# DocumentDB IN keyword with Linq

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

You can now create IN queries with DocumentDB like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Families 
WHERE Families.id IN ('AndersenFamily', 'WakefieldFamily')
```

But if I run a similar query with Linq I get an error ***{"Method 'Contains' is not supported."}***

```
.where(a => familyNames.Contains(a.Families))
```

**How can I crate IN queries with Linq?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN` is not currently supported by the LINQ provider.

We will fix this in a future SDK update.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed now, what you have should work with the new SDK releases.