# Pass list of strings as a Parameter in Parameterized Query in DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, parameterized-query

Is there a way i can pass a list of strings in the SqlParameter, lets say i have 10 authors and i want to find books published by them. I know i can make 10 parameters in (new SqlParameter) separately. But is there a way to just pass a list and get the results.

```
IQueryable<Book> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(collectionSelfLink,
            new SqlQuerySpec
            {
                QueryText = "SELECT * FROM books b WHERE (b.Author.Name = @name)", 
                Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection() 
                { 
                      new SqlParameter("@name", "Herman Melville")
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the SQL `IN` keyword, see [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/) for more information.

Usage example:

```
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE books.Author.Name IN ('Helena Petrovna Blavatsky', 
'Hermes Trismegistus', 'Heinrich Cornelius Agrippa')
```

Comment: Can this thing " 'Helena Petrovna Blavatsky', 
'Hermes Trismegistus', 'Heinrich Cornelius Agrippa' " be passed as a parameter in Parameters, because i am trying to avoid the sql injection i want to pass a list of strings in Parameters, Can it happen ?

Comment: @himanshukaushal The SQL `IN` Keyword is not supported yet in the DocumentDB Linq Provider AFAIK, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870123/documentdb-in-keyword-with-linq . A workaround until they support the `IN` Keywords woudl be to execure the SQL query as above, and you can pass in a list of comma-seperated array elements using the `String.Join(",", authorsArray)` method.